# linq or sql smart way to make a separate order by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

**Data:**

[image]

I want to order data like the image above:

```
var expiredDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6);

var query=*;

var first=query.Search(o=>o.PreorderTime<expiredDate&&(o.TotalMoney-o.MoneyPaid)>0); //  this on the top

var second=query.Search(o=>o.PreorderTime>=expiredDate&&(o.TotalMoney-o.MoneyPaid)>0);

var third=query.Search(o=>(o.TotalMoney-o.MoneyPaid)<=0);

var left= query.Search(o=>!first.Contains(o)&&!second.Contains(o)&&!third.Contains(o));

var all = first.Concat(second).Concat(third).Concat(left);

var result=all.AsEnumerable().Select((item, index) => new{...,Index=index}).Take(pagesize).OrderBy(o=>o.Index).Skip(pagesize*(pageindex-1));
```

I test the result ,I can get first page, but after second page,no data.I don't know why.
Is there a smart way to order this data?

Comment: Looks like `first`, `second` and `third` cover all the data, what `left` is supposed to do? Also, in order to get predictable paging results, the items inside the "groups" must be ordered by something which is not seen in your example. And lastly, are you sure you have data for more than one page?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (hope you can manage the actual projection)

```
var query = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 11), Name = "Jim", MoneyPaid = 0, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 2, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 09), Name = "Sim", MoneyPaid = 500, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 3, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 10), Name = "Sim", MoneyPaid = 1100, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 4, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 19), Name = "Long", MoneyPaid = 3200, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 5, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 29), Name = "Long", MoneyPaid = 200, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 6, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 08), Name = "Long", MoneyPaid = 5000, TotalMoney = 5000 },
    new { Id = 7, PreorderTime = new DateTime(2015, 11, 28), Name = "Long", MoneyPaid = 5000, TotalMoney = 5000 },
};
var expiredDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6);
int pageSize = 3;
int pageCount = (query.Length + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pageCount; pageIndex++)
{
    var page = query
        .OrderBy(o => o.TotalMoney - o.MoneyPaid > 0 ? o.PreorderTime < expiredDate ? 0 : 1 : 2)
        .ThenByDescending(o => o.PreorderTime)
        .Skip(pageSize * (pageIndex - 1))
        .Take(pageSize)
        //.Select(...)
        .ToList();
}
```